# Solspace Tag 4.2.6 Update Broken with EE 2.8.1

Tags: solspace, solspace-tag, 2.8

I just downloaded the latest update for Solspace Tag 4.2.6 and immediately received the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::userdata() in /projects/myproject/system/expressionengine/libraries/Csrf.php on line 391`

Reverting back to the previous version (4.2.5) resolved the issue. There is something broken in the update.

Comment: What other 3rd-party add-ons do you have installed?

Comment: A few: Structure, CE Cache, AB Pagination, Low Reorder, Super Search, Title Master, Single Entry, Stash

Comment: I'm having an issue as well. Recently upgraded to EE 2.8.1 and Tag 4.2.7. When I load a page with Tag associations, I get: Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Loader::libary() in /public_html/system/expressionengine/libraries/EE_Pagination.php on line 237

Comment: Never mind. This was an EE issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug when Tag is used with other addons that add cache variables to the Sessions object before it actually exists.

A workaround for the issue will be in Tag 4.2.7, which we are testing for release.

Comment: I assume that this update will include freeform also?

Comment: Yes, it's an issue that affects most of our add-ons, and will be corrected across the board :)